# Multiple Alert Views in iOS

Tags: ios, uialertview

In a view controller I have two alert views:

```
  if (!self.puntoOrigen.latitude){
            UIAlertView *alertView1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                                      @"Debe seleccionar un punto de recojo" message:@"Para ello, centre el punto deseado en la pantalla y pulse el botón O" delegate:self
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            alertView1.tag = 1;
            [alertView1 show];


        }

        NSLog(@"SESION INICIADA, PUEDE SOLICITAR TAXI");
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nuevo_servicio_segue" sender:self];
    }
    if (sesion != 1){


        NSLog(@"SESION NO INICIADA, NO PUEDE SOLICITAR TAXI");
    // alerta con dos opciones

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                                  @"No has iniciado sesión" message:@"Para poder continuar escoje una de las siguientes opciones" delegate:self
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Regístrame" otherButtonTitles:@"Iniciar sesión", nil];
        alertView.tag = 2;
        [alertView show];

    }
```

And then the method for both alert views:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:
(NSInteger)buttonIndex{


    if (alertView.tag ==1){
         NSLog(@"ESTOY AQU");
        switch (buttonIndex) {

            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    if (alertView.tag == 2){
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"iniciar_registro_segue" sender:self];
            break;
        case 1:

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"iniciar_sesion_segue" sender:self];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    }


}
```

Both alert views are shown when needed, the problem is that the method does always launch the second condition, "if alertView.tag==2".

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Use uialertviewcontroller instead if you're targetting iOS 8. Uialertview has been deprecated.

Comment: @Fogmeister, thank you. I am targetting iOS8, but  I am not getting any message or warning that could force the behaviour. You mean I should only change the  name UIAlertView for UIAlertViewController  and it should work? I will try, of course.

Comment: @user4619034 that's because it's deprecated, which in layman terms means, it will usually support this current iOS version of deprecation in it's entirety, but will more than likely discontinue it in the next major iOS version, so by transitioning to `UIAlertController` you will get neither a warning nor risk potential crashes. Additionally `UIAlertController` is far superior to its counterpart, with built in completion handlers, which is what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you logged the tag? after setting and then at the delegate?
Also, you shouldn't use if and if condition for this. It should be if and elseIf.

Reason: well you are not checking for one condition and then checking another condition. It is either this condition or the other condition. This way it won't go through all if statements (unless you are of course checking for separate conditions).

Also I don't see the reason to add a tag here. You can reference the text in the button or the message itself inside the delegate.

```html
NSString *buttonTitle = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

if([buttonTitle isEqualToString:title1]) do something..
else if([buttonTitle isEqualToString:title2]) do something else..
```

and you can set those titles to const NSStrings or a MACRO.

```html
NSString * const title1 = @"Debe seleccionar un punto de recojo"
```

or, simply compare the message of the alertView itself in the delegate instead:

```html
NSString *msg = [alertView message];

if([msg isEqualToString:msg1]) do something..
else if([msg isEqualToString:msg2]) do something else..

// and then declare the message as const NSString or MACRO.

NSString *const msg1 = @"Para ello, centre el punto deseado en la pantalla y pulse el botón O"
NSString *const msg2 = @"Para poder continuar escoje una de las siguientes opciones"
```

And of course, you can use a combination of these to your use case.

Comment: Comparing alert titles/messages is actually worse than using tags. It will fail once you can't use the constant string. For example because you want to localize the app, or if the message becomes dynamic. Besides keeping the alert in a instance variable, `tag` is the best way.

Comment: I do agree, but that part you need to handle. If you are localizing the app you need to have a separate localizable.strings and grab them instead.